# How to align an element to the bottom of the window using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a html-5 banner using Adobe Animate and have an element, which should be aligned to the bottom of the window depending on the height of this window.

My banner should be 100% height and on the [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucyrQ.png) picture you can see the right position of the bottom elements. And on the [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJkhI.png) picture there is a space between the element and the background. 
And my element should remain aligned to the bottom when changing the height of the window. How can I do it using js?

Here is my code which helps me move the element but it doesn't align it to the bottom:

```
this.frame_0 = function() {

    var _second = this.second;

    this.addEventListener("tick", res.bind(this));
    function res() {
    _second.y =  window.innerHeight/2 + 120;

    }
}
```

This is my [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xv9hk8u9aemnw5d/kufar.zip?dl=0)

Comment: `tick` isn't a standard JavaScript event -- unless you've built such an event, you function will never get executed. Also, you'd probably be better off using CSS to solve this task rather than JavaScript -- could you please add your HTML to form a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i added a link in my question
please, check it
thanks

Answer (score 1):

use CSS to set the positions of element.

```
position:fixed;
left:ValueFromLeft;
bottom:0;
```

It's easy

Comment: you can use element.style.bottom=value; too.

Comment: i can't do it using css, cause I using a canvas

Comment: Then place it at (X,canvas.height-bannetHeight)

Answer (score 1):

If use CreateJS then you are using a canvas.
CSS solutions don't work, only JS.

Use the Window's resize event.

```
this.frame_0 = function() {
  var _second = this.second;

  function setSecondToTheBottom() {
    _second.y = window.innerHeight - (_second.nominalBounds.height / 2);
  }

  setSecondToTheBottom();

  window.addEventListener("resize", setSecondToTheBottom);
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering
unfortunately it doesn't work , can I please send you the whole archive?

Comment: I found the problem. I update the answer. Now It works!